# How to pass a findAll sliced tag list in BeautifSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

i now i can pass a tag list in `soup.findAll()` like `soup.findAll(['h2', 'h3', 'h4,])`
but for 2 of the tags, i'm only interested in specific ones. in my example :
`soup.findAll('h2')[0]`, `soup.findAll('h3')[7:11]` and `soup.findAll('h4')[:7]`

Is there a way to do that or at least to put the specific sliced tags in the same `bs4.element.ResultSet`?

Thanks !

Comment: `for a[0], b[7:11], c[:7] in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally went with this solution :

```
tags = [soup.findAll('h2')[0], soup.findAll('h3')[7:11], soup.findAll('h4')[:7]]
articles = [i for tag in tags for i in tag]
```